# wordpress setting API Illegal string offset error in my code

Tags: php, wordpress, api, setting

hi to day start to create the setting API write coding to create simple option page for my theme this is my full code

when run the my code it is appear this error

Warning: Illegal string offset 'jw_banner_heading' in C:\wamp\www\wp39\wp-content\plugins\JW_Options\jw_options.php on line 65

please how can solve this problem??

```
<?php
```

class JW_Options {

```
private $options;

public function __construct() {
    add_action('admin_menu', array($this, 'add_menu_page') );
    add_action('admin_init', array($this, 'register_settings_and_fields'));

    //get_option($option_name);
    $this->options = get_option('jw_plugin_options');
}

public function add_menu_page() {
    // it is add the menu page to the settings page in the dashboard
    //add_options_page( $page_title, $menu_title, $capability, $menu_slug, $function);
    add_options_page('Theme Options', 'Theme Options', 'administrator', __FILE__, array($this, 'display_options_page'));
}

public function display_options_page() {
?>
    <div class="wrap">
        <h2>MY Theme Options</h2>
        <form action="options.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <!-- outputs action and options_page fields for a setting page -->
            <!-- settings_fields( $option_group ); -->
            <?php settings_fields( 'jw_plugin_options' ); ?>
            <!-- do_settings_sections( $page ); -->
            <?php do_settings_sections( __FILE__ ); ?>
            <p class="submit">
                <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" class="button button-primary" value="Save Settings">
            </p>
        </form>
    </div>
<?php
}

public function register_settings_and_fields() {
    //delete_option('jw_plugin_options');
    //register_setting( $option_group, $option_name, $sanitize_callback );
    register_setting('jw_plugin_options', 'jw_plugin_options' );
    //add_settings_section( $id, $title, $callback, $page );
    add_settings_section('jw_main_section', 'Main Settings', array($this, 'jw_main_section_cb'), __FILE__);
    //add_settings_field( $id, $title, $callback, $page, $section, $args );
    add_settings_field('jw_banner_heading', 'Banner Heading', array($this, 'jw_banner_heading_setting'), __FILE__, 'jw_main_section');
    add_settings_field('jw_logo', 'Your Logo', array($this, 'jw_logo_setting'), __FILE__, 'jw_main_section');
}

public function jw_main_section_cb() {

}

public function jw_banner_heading_setting() {
    echo "<input type='text' name='jw_plugin_options[jw_banner_heading]' id='jw_banner_heading' value='{$this->options['jw_banner_heading']}' />"; 
}

public function jw_logo_setting() {
    echo '<input type="file" name="jw_logo_upload" />';
}
```

}

if( is_admin() )
$JW_Options = new JW_Options();

?>

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a sanitize callback function
2. Click on the save button